# THREEjs resizing canvas with click

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm currently trying to find a way to resize my threejs/webgl canvas with this function

```
function resize(){
    $('#canvas').css('height', '100%');
    $('#canvas').css('z-index', '1');

    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / parseInt($('#canvas').css('height'));
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, parseInt($('#canvas').css('height'))); 
}
```

It gets the job done, however it just jumps to 100% and I was wondering if there was a way to get a smooth transition

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS transitions if you aren't too strict on backward compatibility.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions

Comment: I've actually tried css transitions but it never actually updates the screen. I even resorted to putting the transition into a loop and adding one pixel at a time and re-rendering the screen each pixel but it still just jumps

Comment: That's strange.  Both "height" and "z-index" are on the list of animatable attributes.  Maybe post a JSFiddle of your attempt so we can see what's going on?

Comment: Using css transitions alone will resize the canvas, but will not call the renderer.setsize function each frame. I think the canvas element fires a resize event which you should listen to to call the renderer.setSize function. So the answer here only gives part of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

So i was unsuccessful in resizing the canvas through resize events, even though it was entering my callback function. Instead of relying on DOM events, I straight just put the resize into my animation loop like so

```
if(expand){
    var temp = parseInt($('#canvas').css('height'));
    temp+=11.5;
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, temp );
    $('#canvas').css('height', temp);
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / parseInt($('#canvas').css('height'));
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
}
```

It's kind of a sloppy solution, but I only need it to do a single resize and then the page itself gets redirected somewhere else.